# How to use Jenkins environment variable in makefile

Tags: jenkins, makefile, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have makefile (GNUmake) in which I would like to use current release number for some operation. The best way I could think of is somehow make Jenkins export this as environment variable that is accessible within makefile when build is going on. I know similar thing is possible in ant and Jenkins but not sure how can I achieve same using makefile.

Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function that runs a shell command (or makefile, or anything that generates output),  and returns that output.

```
def getShellScriptResults() {
    def bashresult = sh(
        script: """
            # run here shell script or anything that generates output 
            echo "bashValue"
        """,
        returnStdout: true
    )
    return bashresult.trim()
}
```

Then call the function and assign the result to a groovy var like this :

```
node('mynode') {
    stage('Cloning repositories') {
        # call the function and capture the result to a groovy var
        res = getShellScriptResults()
        println(res)
    }
}
```